# MUI TextField format input to show numbers and decimals

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, format, textfield

I'm trying to format the value of the input of [**this**](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) MUI component to show a maximum of 3 numbers following with a maximum of 2 decimals separated by a dot, e.g. **233.99**, I want to store this value in a react state called value (const [value, setValue] = useState(0)).

I'm having trouble since I see a lot of approachs to achieve this, but I find it complicated to also keep track if the user already entered the first 3 numbers and not let him enter more while also keeping tack of the decimal values too, since as I said, there should be a maximum of 2 decimals.
I tried regex functions, toFixed js function, and more, but I can't make this work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you can achieve this with:

```js
let inp = document.getElementById("input");
inp.addEventListener("keypress", ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (!/\d|\./.test(ev.key)) return;
  inp.value = /^\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(inp.value + ev.key) ? inp.value + ev.key : inp.value;
  // update state when value has changed
  // if (inp.value != value) setValue(inp.value);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Alternatively, you can use `<input type="text" pattern="^\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$">` and `input.checkValidity()` to notify the user on submit.